# Python two loops running one iteration each at a time

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm doing some experimenting with Python args and kwargs and ran into an unexpected issue.  My code is:

```
def argsandkwargs(*args,**kwargs):
    sum = 0
    for arg in args:
        sum += arg
        print(sum)
    for i, j in kwargs.items():
        print('i is ' + i + ' and j is ' + j)

argsandkwargs(5,2,3,6,3,7,actor='RDJ',movie='Iron Man')
```

The output is:

```
5
i is movie and j is Iron Man
i is actor and j is RDJ
7
i is movie and j is Iron Man
i is actor and j is RDJ
10
i is movie and j is Iron Man
i is actor and j is RDJ
16
i is movie and j is Iron Man
i is actor and j is RDJ
19
i is movie and j is Iron Man
i is actor and j is RDJ
26
i is movie and j is Iron Man
i is actor and j is RDJ
```

If the args and kwargs loops are separate, I would expect to see:

```
5
7
10
16
19
26
5
i is movie and j is Iron Man
i is actor and j is RDJ
```

Why is python behaving this way?  It looks like it's running one iteration at a time from each loop, instead of all iterations from each loop before moving to the next.

Comment: Are you sure your indentation is correct?

Comment: Double check that you're not mixing spaces and tabs. Python thinks the second for loop is indented to the same level as the print statement above it.

Comment: Yes, it runs perfectly. Your indentation is off!

Comment: It was the spaces vs tab indentation.  If an indent is equal to 4 spaces, why did the spaces cause an issue like this?

Comment: The indent being equal to 4 spaces is only a feature of your editor. Python 2 treats tabs as 8 spaces, and Python 3 will give you an error for mixing them.

Answer (score 0):

> Double check that you're not mixing spaces and tabs. Python thinks the second for loop is indented to the same level as the print statement above it.

Thank you @Kevin, I had spaces for the first loops, and indents for the second; didn't realize python differentiated these.